# A System to serve geolocation related data

Tags: php, android, web-services

I've been working on an app which basically will send current location to a web server and the web server will do stuff based on that geolocation.

The main task of the webserver is to find sender's friends, who're around the area the sender is in (around the current geolocation of the sender).

I have been thinking about a GIS which solves this problem, but many times it seems pretty vague.

Any pointers to any already existing Open Source implementations of such GIS or to a way to create one from scratch using LAMP would be very helpful.

Sorry if this isn't a right place for this kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Postgis, a postgres project.

Start reading here:

http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/

Hope that helps.

Comment: sounds good. reading through it. Any idea if anything similar exists for MySql too? I am basically at level 0 in Postgre SQL

Comment: I am reading some good words about PostGIS. Planning to go with it only if it satisfies my needs. Thanks!

Comment: You have to make a distinction between the GIS data and the tools to use it (databases). Depending on what you need to find out with geo, you use a different database. For example: a foresters database will store information about trees in area's, where you seem to calculate only distance. If you have a pair of latitude/longitude you can calculate the distance yourself. (google for the formula's. In case you are only interested in close proximity, treat the earth flat. :P )

Comment: If you plan to go with postgres (good choice!), you will find there are a few good (free) books around, eg: http://www.database-books.us/postgresql_0003.php practical prostgresql. AN old book, but that was my studybook (on real paper).

Comment: That's some valuable piece of information. The only problem would be that I wanted to start on it quickly, but it seems it won't be very easily done now.

Comment: One question: Do you only need the distance based on 1 pair of long/lat? If the distance isn't far and you only care about absolute distance (as real distance, like a birdflight, I don't remember the right English phrase for that), than you can simply use pythagoras.

Comment: Probably yes, but basically a system which receives a geolocation and searches for records "around" that geolocation is what I am looking for. it can be flat for sure. And I think the term is called 'bearing of earth' :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18048/discussion-between-erwin-moller-and-sheikh-aman)